# take screenshot on web page with flash element

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas, screenshot

**I would like to take a screenshot of a page displayed in a WebView.** The page may contains **flash elements**, I refer to **google feedback**, but when I take a screenshot all the flash parts of the page are blank.

The flash element(for example video) can not be controlled because it is not my own website.

Beside I do not want to use any **extension of browser**.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to take a screenshot of Flash elements on the webpage using JavaScript embedded on the same page. All available JS solutions ([more details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots)) are reading current DOM state and rendering (using JS render engine implementation) a web page on a canvas element. Flash object is executed by separate application - Flash Player. JS can't access its contents, there is no Flash render engine implementation in JS.

However, since you mentioned WebView and you are talking about Flash then I assume that you are working on the native Android app. Therefore, it should be fairly easy for a native app to create a screenshot ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)).